# Database Schema with Localization

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating an application with localization and SQL table.

I am wondering which approach should I use to create my tables.

**OPTION 1**

One table (Posts) for common data and another (Posts_Localized) for each culture.

```
create table dbo.Posts
(
  Id int identity not null,
  Created datetime not null
);

create table dbo.Posts_Localized
(
  Id int not null,
  [Culture] int not null 
    constraint CK_Culture check ([Culture] in ('1', '2', '3')), // EN, FR, DE
  Title nvarchar (200) not null
);
```

**OPTION 2**

One table (Posts) for all data ... Each record has a KEY.

Versions EN, PT, FR will share a KEY because are different versions of the same post.

```
create table dbo.Posts
(
  Id int identity not null,
  Created datetime not null,
  [Culture] int not null 
    constraint CK_Culture check ([Culture] in ('1', '2', '3')), // EN, FR, DE
  Title nvarchar (200) not null,
  [Key] uniqueidentifier not null
);
```

I see advantages on the second one because:

1. There will be less joins;
2. If I decide that a column might change from common to not common I will not need to change the database Schema ...

What do you think?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: if you have more tables other then this then you should use the first approach as it will be normalized form otherwise the 2nd one is good.

Comment: Well, I have Posts and many other tables: Posts and Posts_Localized, Slides and Slides_Localized, Products and Products_Localized ... So you saying that I should use option 2 because I have many tables? Maybe I miss understood your answer ...

Comment: if you want to fetch the data by performing join with this table and other table then you should use the first approach ,otherwise 2nd one is good.i hope you have knowledge about *normalizations* in DBMS.

Comment: Yes, I do want to fetch data with this table and others ... For example, Posts table can have a NxN relation with Tags table ... or Posts_Localized can have a NxN relation to a Files table ...

Comment: so its better you use OPTION 1

Comment: About normalization would you add culture with a Join to a Cultures table or add a constraint as I just added now. The reason why I added a constraint is because it makes easy to map that column to a Enum in C#. So I can have a CulturesEnum with all the cultures valid in my application which would map directly ... But again, I am not sure which way to go.

Comment: sorry i dont have any idea for this:(